# Call to web service in php

Tags: php, web-services, soapui

I have to do a call to a webservice using php. The only information that I have is an example call for SoapUI like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:web="http://somewhere.at/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <web:authenticate>
      <user-name>mmann</user-name>
      <password>787cef7a4e1ff51fcc920ad62aaa6df2df99a4bb</password>
    </web:authenticate>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I do a similar call using php?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Comment: cloevoting because tutorials about using SOAP with PHP should be easily findable on the web. Also, the question does not show any research effort whatsoever. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

- [Webservice call from PHP – wsdl2php makes it simple](http://www.sajithmr.me/webservice-call-from-php-wsdl2php-makes-it-simple/)
- [SOAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) (php.net)

Comment: How do I find out where is the wsdl file?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [nusoap](http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapprogwsdl.htm). and use [soapui](http://www.soapui.org/) to test the webservice itself.
hope this helps